# Change border width without moving other table elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table of buttons that when clicked increase their border width from 1px to 3px. I have looked at [Javascript - Changing border-width without moving surrounding elements.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149996/javascript-changing-border-width-without-moving-surrounding-elements), [Don't affect positioning of other elements on border-width changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38165317/dont-affect-positioning-of-other-elements-on-border-width-changes) and [How to add padding or border to a DIV and keep width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675478/how-to-add-padding-or-border-to-a-div-and-keep-width-and-height) but none of these helped. I have also tried the box-sizing and outline properties and neither work. I have this Javascript:

```
function cur(curval) {
    if (!prevElement) {
      prevElement = document.getElementById(curval);
      currentElement = prevElement;
    } else {
      prevElement = currentElement;
      prevElement.style.borderWidth = "1px"
      currentElement = document.getElementById(curval);
    }
    currentElement.style.borderWidth = "3px"
    document.body.style.cursor = curval;
}
```

Here is part of the table:

```
<tr>
    <td><button id="default" onclick="cur('default')"><img 
    src="default.png"/></button></td>
    <td><button id="alias" onclick="cur('alias')"><img src="alais.png"/>
    </button></td>
    <td><button id="cell" onclick="cur('cell')"><img src="cell.png"/>
    </button></td>
    <td><button id="col-resize" onclick="cur('col-resize')"><img src="col-
    resize.png"/></button></td>
    <td><button id="copy" onclick="cur('copy')"><img src="copy.png"/>
    </button></td>
    <td><button id="crosshair" onclick="cur('crosshair')"><img 
    src="crosshairs.png"/></button></td>
</tr>
```

All the buttons have `border: 1px solid black` until they are clicked on.
How could I make it so the border-width does not affect the other elements in the table?

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML as well.

Comment: HTML Please????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add padding to the table cell equal to the difference of the border size.

So if the largest border width is going to be `3px`, when the button is not selected, your table cell should have a padding of `2px` and your button should have a border of `1px`.  When the button is selected the table cell should have a padding of `0` and the button should have a border of `3px`.

In this manner, no visible change will be made when selecting a button.